# Use iPhone as a wireless track pad for ubuntu 12.10 64

Tags: 12.10, iphone

Anyone know a good app that can use my iphone 3gs as a track pad?

Comment: Remote control for what?

Comment: *as remote or ubuntu* OR *as remote* **of** *ubuntu*

Comment: I want to be able to use my iphone as a wireless trackpad for presentations, specifically for prezi presentations

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/280924/329036