# how to make iphone as a mouse via bluetooth

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, mouse, bluetooth, iphone

Ubuntu 12.10, Bluetooth 2.0

I'm looking for a way to use my iphone as a mouse using bluetooth connection. It's already and certainly work when I'm using Mac or Windows. The reason why I want to use bluetooth is because when I try use adhoc connection, there is a lag between my iphone(mouse) and output on the computer.

Anyone know how to setup iphone's mouse via bluetooth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## touchmoused

I found a project called `touchmoused` that simulates Logitech Touch Mouse app.

### Description

touchmouchd will act as a server for Logitech's Touch Mouse app for IOS or
other clients using the same network protocol. The Logitech Touch Mouse app will
allow you to control your mouse and keyboard using your IOS device.

### Implemented features

- Mouse buttons
- Mouse movement
- Two-finger scroll
- Alphanumeric key support (1..9, a..z, A..Z)
- Modifier key support (Ctrl, Alt)
- Some other keys

[The software is in fact a daemon](https://github.com/mycroes/touchmoused/blob/master/touchmoused) so save the script, make it executable and have a look at the `help` at the bottom on how to use it. It is a year old and looks like an coding example attempt so mileage may vary

---

## Remotepad

Besides that there is an app called [Remotepad](http://www.tenjin.org/RemotePad/downloads.html) in your store.

### Description

RemotePad is an open source application that controls the mouse cursor of your desktop PC. This way, you can use your iPhone or iPod touch as a wireless touchpad!

### Overview

- Mouse control with a virtual touchpad.
- Software keyboard for ascii text inputs.
- Server support for major platforms, namely, Mac OS X, Windows, Linux and BSD.
- Bonjour (Zeroconf) server detection under Mac OS X.
- Customizable appearence and behaviour.

  - number of buttons to display
  - tap clicking and dragging
  - dragging with mouse button dragging
  - landscape mode
  - two finger tapping for secondary click
  - button location (triple tapping and continuously dragging to move)
- Vertical and horizontal scrolling.
  with two fingers
  with center button dragging

  - Mouse (pseudo)control via accelerometer.
  - Send arrow keys. (double tapping and continuously dragging to enter arrow keys)
- Demo mode.

  - you can show a tap view and a setup view without any servers (to enter a demo mode, tap your iPhone name and hold four seconds)
  - nothing happen :-)

### Dependencies

Remotepad requires `build-essential` and `libxtst-dev` to run. You can install them with the command:

```
sudo apt install build-essential libxtst-dev
```

Download [remotepad source code](http://iphone-remotepad.googlecode.com/files/RemotePadServer-1.10-X11-Source.tgz).

### Installation

- `sudo apt-get install build-essential libxtst-dev`
- Download the remotepad and move it to `/opt` or where ever you want if not `/opt`.
- Untar/Unzip the package and this will create a directory called `RemotePad Server`
- `cd ~/"RemotePad Server"/X11` and "make" it...

  ```
  ./configure
  make
  sudo make install
  ```
- To start it run `remotepad`.

[Source #1](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1153977&highlight=remotepad) and [Source #2](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1025200)

Comment: I already noted both apps already but unfortunately they do not support connection using bluetooth between iPhone and Linux-PC as a mouse. What they make is, the pc and the iPhone connect to the same wireless network like as between wireless HDD and my Linux. The difference is the Linux hear the signal from the iPhone only, while between wireless HDD and Linux-PC, it on both side. I guess, we might don't have it or will not have it.

Comment: As of October 2017, on Ubuntu 16.04, touchmoused worked well for me. It is, however, over wifi, not bluetooth.

Comment: @Prime624 over wifi, you mean both connected to a third wifi service or connected to each other directly?

Comment: @MycrofD Third wifi service. They both need to be on the same wifi network (and the network must allow this type of connection). So, for example, this doesn't work on a college wifi network, but works fine at a home.

Comment: @Prime624 how to make the college wifi network allow this connection then? probably no solution yet :( ?

Comment: @MycrofD I don't know of a way. At least at my school, they lock the network down pretty well.